# drush ard fails with error Database dump failed, drush 5.10.0 drupal 7.39

Tags: 7, drush

```
sudo drush ard -v --destination=sites/default/files/sitearchive.tgz
```

fails with error "Database dump failed"

```
Initialized Drupal 7.39 root directory at /var/www/drupal                                                                                                                 [notice]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default                                                                                                                          [notice]
php /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php  --backend=2 --verbose --root=/var/www/drupal --uri=http://default  sql-conf   --all 2>&1                                              [notice]
Executing: tar  --exclude "drupal/sites" --dereference -cf /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/drupal.20161018_203926.tar drupal
Executing: tar  --dereference -rf /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/drupal.20161018_203926.tar drupal/sites/all
Executing: tar --dereference -rf /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/drupal.20161018_203926.tar drupal/sites/README.txt
Executing: tar --dereference -rf /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/drupal.20161018_203926.tar drupal/sites/example.sites.php
Executing: mysqldump --result-file /tmp/drush_tmp_1476823166_5806887e850ef/drupal.sql --no-autocommit --single-transaction --opt -Q  drupal --host=xxxxxx.ceiixl6nbq74.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --user=xxxxxxx --password='xxxxxxxxx'
Database dump failed.                                                                                                                                                  [error]
Command dispatch complete
```

I haven't really used Drush, but I'm working through migrating a site to Pantheon and this is the way they suggest.

Here is the output of drush status. (the xs are subbed in for identifiable info)

```
sudo drush status
 Drupal version                  :  7.39
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  xxxxx.ceiixl6nbq74.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
 Database username               :  xxxxx
 Database name                   :  xxxxx
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :  Anonymous
 Default theme                   :  mytheme
 Administration theme            :  mytheme
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 Drush version                   :  5.10.0
 Drush configuration             :
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/drupal
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Attempting to run the mysqldump command as shown in the output of the drush command (as suggested in the comments) simply returns 'mysqldump: command not found'

Can anyone shed some light on this problem? I have zero experience with drush so I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot it.

I'm happy to provide any additional information deemed useful.

Comment: Try running the `mysqldump` command shown in the debug info.

Comment: Tried that and I get a 'command not found' error for mysqldump.

Comment: Any message in mysql error log?

Answer (score 1):

If `mysqldump` is not found, it means that you miss the mysql-client or mysql-client-5.5 package (if you are using Debian). Your version of Drush indicates that you are using Debian as it is severely outdated ;-)